# Slow application startup over JNLP in production environment in network without Internet connection

Tags: java, apache, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm doing an application launched via JNLP and I'm seeing a strange slow action when running it in a production environment on a network without Internet access.
After downloading and validating, the application pulls the jars listed in the jnlp file and freezes.
In the java console after activating the detailed login by pressing 5, entries appear that the Apache web server is searched for the presence of class files from the inside of the jars used in our application.

```
...

10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:03 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/faflute_kr.jnlp HTTP/1.1" 200 92089 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:17 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/faflute_kr.jnlp HTTP/1.1" 200 92090 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:17 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 7508 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:17 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/win32/rxtxSerial.dll.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 60720 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:17 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 16282 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 462659 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:17 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/faflute_kr.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 10313262 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 8782 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 66741 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 39196 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/axis-saaj-1.4.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 24784 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/barcode4j-2.1.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 288807 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-anim-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 412567 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-awt-util-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 323135 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-bridge-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 566207 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-css-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 279680 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-dom-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 153465 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-ext-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 15446 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:17 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/ant-1.7.1.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1389265 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-gvt-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 156356 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-parser-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 63542 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-script-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 22204 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-svg-dom-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 230731 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-xml-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 31326 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 200414 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/batik-util-1.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 118762 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/bcmail-jdk14-138.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 200414 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1596904 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 27087 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:18 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/axis-1.4.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1665622 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1596904 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/castor-core-1.3.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 56959 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:19 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/castor-xml-1.3.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 922709 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:20 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 245717 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:20 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/commons-cli-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 35256 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:20 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 59514 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:26:20 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 80632 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/11.144.2.01 (<internal>) Java/1.8.0_144"

...
```

All dependencies used in this app are downloaded via Gradle and exported to a lib folder on our Apache Webserver so this should not be a problem with dependecies.
And it occurs case every time it is run in a production environment on the network without access to the Internet.

Here are the logs from Apache when the App freezes during startup:

```
...

10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 587 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 588 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 195 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:40 +0100] "HEAD /krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/cache/spi/QueryCache.class HTTP/1.1" 404 559 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/cache/spi/QueryCache.class HTTP/1.1" 404 559 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/cache/spi/UpdateTimestampsCache.class HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/cache/spi/UpdateTimestampsCache.class HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/dialect/function/SQLFunctionRegistry.class HTTP/1.1" 404 575 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/dialect/function/SQLFunctionRegistry.class HTTP/1.1" 404 575 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/TypeLocatorImpl.class HTTP/1.1" 404 563 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/TypeLocatorImpl.class HTTP/1.1" 404 563 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/engine/query/spi/QueryPlanCache.class HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/engine/query/spi/QueryPlanCache.class HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger_$logger_pl_PL.class HTTP/1.1" 404 579 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger_$logger_pl_PL.class HTTP/1.1" 404 579 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger_$logger_pl.class HTTP/1.1" 404 576 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger_$logger_pl.class HTTP/1.1" 404 576 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap.class HTTP/1.1" 404 589 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap.class HTTP/1.1" 404 589 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$EvictionListener.class HTTP/1.1" 404 606 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$EvictionListener.class HTTP/1.1" 404 606 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction.class HTTP/1.1" 404 598 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:41 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction.class HTTP/1.1" 404 598 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction$1.class HTTP/1.1" 404 600 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction$1.class HTTP/1.1" 404 600 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction$2.class HTTP/1.1" 404 600 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction$2.class HTTP/1.1" 404 600 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction$3.class HTTP/1.1" 404 600 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Eviction$3.class HTTP/1.1" 404 600 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$EvictionPolicy.class HTTP/1.1" 404 604 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$EvictionPolicy.class HTTP/1.1" 404 604 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$NullEvictionListener.class HTTP/1.1" 404 610 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$NullEvictionListener.class HTTP/1.1" 404 610 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"
10.33.65.110 - - [20/Feb/2018:13:33:42 +0100] "GET /krzysiek/lib/org/hibernate/internal/util/collections/BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Segment.class HTTP/1.1" 404 597 "-" "Java/1.8.0_144"

...
```

When a host on witch this app is launched is connected to the Internet, it loads quickly and after downloading all jars to the local machine, it reads everything from the local cache.

On the client side in Java Console when the Application freezes in production enviroment it looks like below:

```
...

network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/log4j.properties, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/log4j.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/krzysiek/lib/org/apache/log4j/LayoutBeanInfo.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT

...
```

On a host with Internet connection it looks like below (older logs):

```
...
security: Grant connect perm for http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar : java.security.Permissions@b093f5 (
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80/-" "*:*")
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80" "*:*")
)

ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for appRef=
        type: JNLP
        title: Faflute Inpolpapier
        location: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp
        htmlLocation: null
        jnlpLocation: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp
        anchorURL: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp, codeRef = 
        jar location: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
        jar version: null
ruleset: no exception applies, returning Rule: DefaultRule
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
security: Istrusted: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp false
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Verified non-main jar: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@f7815ec2: 3
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@f7815ec2: 4
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://localhost/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@6f275de9: 3
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://localhost/lib/FDBHelper.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@ce67b02c: 3
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@f7815ec2: 3
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://localhost/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@6f275de9: 2
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://localhost/lib/FDBHelper.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@ce67b02c: 2
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://localhost/lib/jcalendar.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@f7815ec2: 2
security: Grant connect perm for http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar : java.security.Permissions@1ba1cb1 (
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80/-" "*:*")
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80" "*:*")
)

ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for appRef=
        type: JNLP
        title: Faflute Inpolpapier
        location: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp
        htmlLocation: null
        jnlpLocation: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp
        anchorURL: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp, codeRef = 
        jar location: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
        jar version: null
ruleset: no exception applies, returning Rule: DefaultRule
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
security: Istrusted: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp false
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Verified non-main jar: http://localhost/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.7.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@a9980041: 3
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@a9980041: 4
security: Grant connect perm for http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar : java.security.Permissions@334aff (
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80/-" "*:*")
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80" "*:*")
)

ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for appRef=
        type: JNLP
        title: Faflute Inpolpapier
        location: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp
        htmlLocation: null
        jnlpLocation: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp
        anchorURL: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp, codeRef = 
        jar location: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
        jar version: null
ruleset: no exception applies, returning Rule: DefaultRule
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
security: Istrusted: http://localhost/faflute-kr.jnlp false
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Verified non-main jar: http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@e5c2dec9: 3
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@e5c2dec9: 4
security: Grant connect perm for http://localhost/lib/dynamicreports/jasperreports-6.4.0.jar : java.security.Permissions@1d67f0e (
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80/-" "*:*")
("java.net.URLPermission" "http://localhost:80" "*:*")
)

...
```

Did any of you have anything like that with your Application?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say. Several possibilities: Try to set the timeouts in your [deployment.properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html) file.

deployment.javaws.update.timeout=1;
deployment.security.revocation.check=NO_CHECK
deployment.security.validation.timeout=1;